# How does this code to generate the $k^{th}$ order multifactorial for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ work?

Tags: function-construction

The $k^{th}$ order multifactorial for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is defined commonly as the follows:
[image]

Which is equivalent to

[image]

I saw a succinct line of code on [RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multifactorial) for generating the $k^{th}$ order multifactorial for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ as follows:

```
Multifactorial[n_, k_] := Abs[ Apply[ Times, Range[-n, -1, k]]]
```

Could someone explain me how the code works in a sort of step by step manner since I am unable to quite understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by understanding how `Apply` works. For example

```
Apply[f, {a, b, c}]
```

> f[a,b,c]

So, if you need product of these three numbers, you use

```
Apply[Times, {a, b, c}]
```

> a b c

Now what remains is to find the right elements to multiply. For `k`th multifactorial of `n` it is `{n,n-k,n-2k,...}` which you can write as

```
Range[n,1,-k]
```

Your code construct the series in reverse order and so it requires `Abs` in front. Therefore

```
Multifactorial[n_, k_] := Apply[Times, Range[n, 1, -k]]
```

> (n)(n-k)(n-2k)...

Comment: Thanks that's a good explanation.